# How to use awk build in variable in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I need to use awk build in variable `$NF` with shell script. The input string will be something like this

```
Chapl 222222/0: Pran=28e2 Load=0.000 kkk Statevfe=Nowf Alarmkj fIMmg=1 LkouIM="087" Po89rt="eth566" NE40Ef-02-T1M1N2-HUW_S1_RD
```

I want to extract the last element alone from this string

```
NE40Ef-02-T1M1N2-HUW_S1_RD
```

In the server if I do something like this

```
cat aa |awk '{print $NF}'
```

I get the correct result. But when I try to do ssh and then try to execute the same it does not understand what is `$NF`.

I am trying to do something like this

```
cat aa |awk -v temp ="$NF" '{print $NF}'
```

But this does not work.

Comment: `foo=($(cat aa)); temp="${foo[${#foo[@]}-1]}"`?

Comment: `awk -v temp ="$NF"` will assign the shell variable `NF` to a new `awk` variable `temp` that can be used only inside `awk`. The shell variable `NF` has only the same name as the `awk` variable.

Comment: `temp=$(sed 's/.* //' aa)` removing everything until (including) the last space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
temp=$(awk '{print $NF}' aa)
```

Comment: What if the string is not present in the file. The output in the string is got when I execute a command like "some chn ". This will give list of all links present in the server. Some 100 strings like I listed in the example. I want to get the links which has zero traffic. The link is the last element present in each row. What I want is something like this "some chn" | grep ""Load=  0.000" |awk -v temp=$(awk '{print $NF}' )'{print $temp}' . But this does not work

Answer (score 0):

shell version (ksh, bash)

```
temp='Chapl 222222/0: Pran=28e2 Load=0.000 kkk Statevfe=Nowf Alarmkj fIMmg=1 LkouIM="087" Po89rt="eth566" NE40Ef-02-T1M1N2-HUW_S1_RD'
temp="${temp##* }"


 # or in ssh script using output
 temp="$( cat aa )"
 echo "${temp##* }"
```